# how to convert word file to imges file without using ms.interop.word reference

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to view word files in my website. When using `return File(path,"application/msword");` the Word document is directly downloaded. I want to display the Word document without downloading.

How can I convert word to PDF/image file without using a Microsoft.Interop.Word reference?

Comment: How do you expect to be able to read a Word document without using the interop DLL that Microsoft provide for that purpose?

Comment: ya, but in my server word application did not installed so only i'm asking this question

Comment: see this thread may it help:
[Office documents to PDF][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7665062/office-documents-to-pdf?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't convert a file containing textual/document information to a picture without virtually rendering it or something. And I'm sure that's a bit beyond scope so what you want to do isn't possible. If you want to display word files on the browser, I think the best bet is to convert it to a .pdf and then display it in an easier way, although it's not fast either.

These links may have some bases to help you achieve what you want:

http://www.beansoftware.com/ASP.NET-Tutorials/PDF-View-Custom-Control.aspx
https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Word-file-to-PDF-Conversion-261fd865

In a more complex way, you could use Open Office XML to parse the file and render the relevant contents into the page. Since you want to display the whole document, this might not be the best approach.

Comment: thanks, please tell me how to convert word to .pdf file in mvc4 web application

Comment: Updated the answer with links that can help you.

Comment: Thanks i followed 2nd link it works well in local ( i have installed ms-word in my local machine) but i did't work in server (there is no ms-word installed in  server machine) how can i do this conversion in my server? please help me i'm helpless.

Comment: If you want to use that method, it use word interop so you have to install word on your server. Otherwise, you have to develop something more complex that use OpenOfficeXML.

Comment: They did't allow me to install office in server tell me some other way to achieve the solution, thanks in advance

Comment: otherwise you tell me how to display word document in website without downloading word files

Comment: Like I used, you can use OpenOfficeXML to parse the document and render it into HTML, somehow, but it's highly inneficient. Otherwise, follow the first link and display it as PDF.

Comment: The first link provide information regarding How to Display PDF documents with ASP.NETnot abot word to pdf conversion

Comment: Yeah you need interop.